# Why won't my cookie expiry time change?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am trying to implement my own sign in page for phpmyadmin. So far I have this and it works, but I want the session to only be good for 1 hour.

Code:

```
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60*60);
    session_set_cookie_params(60*60);
    session_name('SignonSession');
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_user'] = $_POST['u'];
    $_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_password'] = $_POST['p'];

    if(!isset($_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_token'])) {
        $_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_token'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    }
```

It lets me log in, but the session is good for one year, which is not what I want. I had thought maybe the cookie would expire after I ended my session, but it was still there. I'm not using a framework and my PHP ini settings are the same.  Does anyone know why my cookies still have a one year expiration date on them even though I'm setting the time in my script?

Comment: I copy-pasted your code on a local server and it set expiration for exactly 1 hour. So the provided code is correct and works as expected.

Comment: hmm. that's interesting. I just noticed that there are two cookies that are created. One expires in one hour and there is another one that is exactly the same that expires in one year?

Comment: And what is the difference between them apart of expiration date?

Comment: they have different values as well

Comment: What else? You must realize that a browser won't keep 2 cookies with identical name if the domain is the same

Comment: The script is set on a sub-domain and then redirected to a main domain.

Comment: How is it relevant to my question about what is the differences between 2 cookies?

Comment: One is .domain.com and the other is just domain.com .. I have session.cookie_domain = .domain.com in my php.ini

Comment: So, here is the answer